# jQuery animation delay not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen similar questions on here but not one where the effect was working on one window but not on a subsequent one.

Using jQuery library 3.4.1.
Code has been tested and is working in Firefox but Chrome won't play nicely - the animation is not there, it just opens or closes the window immediately without the specified delay of 200 microseconds.

It's a simple setup, I have a div with an onclick event which toggles the visibility of another div. The now visible div has another onclick event to close/hide it. Both events have a delay of 200ms.

JS I am using with stated library;

```js
<script>
    /* Window Toggle */
    function toggleWindow() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('window');
        $('#window').toggle(200);
        return false;
    }

    /* Window Close */
    function closeWindow() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('window');
        $('#window').hide(200);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML Setup

```
<div id="trigger-window" onclick="toggleWindow(200); return false;">Open Me</div>
<div id="window" onclick="closeWindow(200); return false;">You have opened me, now close me</div>
```

EDITED:CSS

```
#window {transition:0.5s; display:none;}
/* EDIT -  The above line is problematic with Chrome */
#window {display:none;}
/* Transition effect removed, now it works with Chrome */
```

Further up the page I am using the same js code with a different function name to toggle & close a window and this works perfectly in both Firefox & Chrome browsers.

EDIT: I checked my CSS as above and found the issue. Answer below.

Comment: I've just tested your code in Chrome with your jQuery version and the animation is there and it works like it should. Maybe try a different Chrome version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After checking my CSS the only difference between the first animated window which worked in both Firefox & Chrome was it did not have any transition effect, the second window which Chrome wasn't liking had a transition of 0.5s.

Once I removed the transition effect from the div in the CSS it worked perfectly in Chrome. So it seems Chrome found a conflict between CSS and JavaScript but Firefox did not!